# How to implement the response to the TRACE request in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, http, trace, http-trace

The **HTTP TRACE** method performs a message loop-back test along the path to the target resource, providing a useful debugging mechanism. The final recipient of the request should reflect the message received back to the client as the message body of a 200 (OK) response with a Content-Type of message/http.

Example of an *HTTP* request with the *TRACE method*:
[image]

Example of a response to a request with the *TRACE method*:
[image]

```
const path = require( 'path' );
const express = require( 'express' );      // version 4.x
const favicon = require( 'serve-favicon' );

const app = express();

app .use( favicon( path.join( __dirname, 'assets', 'logo.ico' ) ) );

app.trace( '*', ( req, res ) => {
  // how do I return the entire request in its original form in response?
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request` argument in Express is actually a modified node.js [http.IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage) object so you can get all the request data from it:

```
app.trace( '*', ( req, res ) => {
    res.end(
        `${req.method} ${req.url} HTTP/${req.httpVersion}\r\n` +
        req.rawHeaders.join('\r\n')
    )
});
```

This would generally re-create the request but because you are reconstructing it instead of simply copying it there may be small differences.